# elasticsearch install plugin: Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am trying to install the elasticsearch plugin with the command: `./plugin install license` which I found on this tut: [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/getting-started.html)

But I get the error message:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM 
>   Could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

After that even if I run `java -version` I get the same error! Before I run `./plugin install license` `java -version` worked fine and printed:

> java version "1.7.0_79"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Does anybody know whats my problem here? Its a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and I installed elasticsearch 2.2.3

Comment: How much physical RAM do you have?

Comment: @Val `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal´ gives me MemTotal:     2097152 kB

Comment: Do you have other stuff running on your server that might eat memory? By default ES starts with a 1GB heap, but if there's less RAM available than that, then you can run into such troubles.

Comment: I see that I have 757.024MB free. I am not sure whats eating my memory. I have a fresh install and only installed java, nano and elasticsearch till yet

Comment: What happens if you run `java -Xmx512m -version`? If that works, you can set `ES_MAX_MEM` to `512m` and that will probably get you further.

Comment: I recognized that the elasticsearch service was still runnig,.. i stioped it and the installation worked now. But thank you for your help @Val

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Installation for ElasticSearch

1) Comment entry in C:\\elasticsearch-5.4.0\elasticsearch-5.4.0\config\jvm.options

```
#-Xms2g
#-Xmx2g
```

2) set  ES_JAVA_OPTS as below in elasticsearch.bat

```
set ES_JAVA_OPTS = "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```